# Keystonejs 4.0 File system storage adapter image preview

Tags: keystonejs

How do I get an image preview for a Types.File field in the admin UI.

It says "The [FS adapter supports](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/lib/storage/adapters/fs) all the default Keystone file schema fields. It also additionally supports and enables the filename path (required)." However when I try ([doc](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-localfile)):

```
format: function(item, file){
        return '<img src="/files/'+file.filename+'" style="max-width: 300px">'
    }
```

Nothing appears in the UI

Answer (score 1):

The `format` function hasn't been working for a while as far as I can tell from the Keystone GitHub. I don't know if the function exists in Keystone 4.0. Reference [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/91).

Answer (score 1):

You could fork the current beta and patch the function yourself if you need this immediately.

You can find it at https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/v4.0.0-beta.5/fields/types/file/FileType.js#L81

Doesn't seem right to me, though. I hope they will fix it before releasing 4.0, along with the missing File Array type.

Answer (score 1):

Image previews are now possible in the latest master branch of keystone (see https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/4509). At the moment you need to depend on the git version of keystone, so put this in your `package.json` and run `npm install`:

```
  "keystone": "https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone.git"
```

In your model, specify `thumb: true` on the image field in question. You also need the `url` property in the schema. For example:

```
const storage = new keystone.Storage({
    adapter: keystone.Storage.Adapters.FS,
    fs: {
        path: keystone.expandPath('./uploads/images'), 
        publicPath: '/images/'
    },
    schema: {
        url: true,
    }
})

ImageUpload.add({
    name: { type: Types.Key, index: true },
    image: {
        type: Types.File,
        storage: myStorage,
        thumb: true
    },
    createdTimeStamp: { type: String }
});
```

The admin UI should now show a small preview of the image and a link to it.